# Trying to call a csv file from where it was saved

Tags: python, csv

```
import os
import csv

infile = open("PearsonFebruary2012.csv","rb")

reader = csv.reader(infile)
for i in range(0.17):
    reader.next()
#The reader below this one
print reader.next()

#I am getting the error that reader is an invalid syntax.
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use python 2 syntax in python 3.

Comment: What version of Python is this? Can you show us the *full* traceback of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo. Your `0.17` should be `0,17`.

Marijn correctly points out that there are two problems, since using a float as an argument to `range` generates a `TypeError`.

Comment: That would be a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I just corrected it and yet, it still highlights "reader" in red and says invalid syntax

Comment: @user2965079: What highlights `reader`? Your editor? What editor is that?

Comment: You're right. The `SyntaxError` on print was obscuring the `TypeError` that would be raised next.

Comment: @TimWilder so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Stranac's suggestion looks like a good bet. Python 3 requires you to call print like `print(reader.next())` instead of `print reader.next()` as you would in 2. If you are running 2, more information would be awesome.

Comment: @TimWilder yes I'm running python 3 and yes you were right, the bracket was required. Although, now I am getting an attribute error "AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'". Should "next" be somehow incorporated into "csv_reader(infile)"?

Comment: @You shouldn't be getting the *same* error.  You may be getting a different one, though: instead of `"rb"`, try `open("Pearsonetc", "r", newline="")`.  The required style of opening csv files changed in Python 3.